# Children emitting event freezes UI when parent update occurs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a pretty weird bug
I Have a component that find all the possible client and emit the update (only a number ) to the parent .
If i don't emit, the children component update instantly. but if  emit the value to the Parent, It freezes the UI for about 3 second.

My children component method

```
  calculerRecetteGlobale() {
 let recetteService = new RecetteService(
                    this.form.recetteService, this.form.dateEvenement
                );

                let recetteFinancement = new RecetteFinancement(
                    this.form.recetteFinancement, this.form.dateEvenement
                );

                let recetteLocation = new RecetteLocation(
                    this.form.recetteLocation, this.form.dateEvenement
                );

                this.form.dataRecetteGlobale = [];

                for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {

            // Does the filtering of client

                    }

                const nb = this.form.dataRecetteGlobale.length;

                this.$emit('onCalculatedRG', nb)
}
```

At that point, the children component update perfectly. If I don't emit, everything works fluently

My Parent component template

```
  <div class='mr-4 ml-4 row'>
       {{this.numberRecetteGlobale}
  </div>
 <div class="row mt-4 w-100 fmt-card">
   <option-form 
        @onCalculatedDistance="onCalculatedDistance"
        @onCalculatedRG="onCalculatedRG"
        :allDistance="distance" 
        :annee="optionsAnnee"
        :filter-marque="valueMarque" 
        :documentHeader="documentHeader"
        :filter-modele="valueModele" 
        :data="grid.data">
  </option-form>
</div>
```

And my method onCalculatedRG is basically only

```
  onCalculatedRG(number) {
                this.numberRecetteGlobale = number;
            },
```

If I console.log(number) instead of putting this.numberRecetteGlobale, everything works fluently so it's the update that is taking much time and i dont know why. I really doubt that the processing to determinate the number is the cause of the UI freeze because everything update perfectly if i don't emit to the parent

Comment: Seems like the parent component has some heavy-duty calculations within it's dependencies and they're being triggered when `numberRecetteGlobale` changes.

Comment: How is that possible ? i mean i changed my method on CalculatedRG with just ```   this.form.test = this.form.test + 1 ;
                this.$emit('onCalculatedRG', this.form.test); ``` and ```this.form.test = 0``` in data and the UI still freezes on parent update

Comment: you were right. The problem is with some other function not even related with this post. When the children component is update, for some reason it triggers a parent method called caculateModel. Instead of only triggering the method for the children that was updated, it triggers the method for each of the 20 parent children. That is a weird behavior. Think ill just create another thread. Thank you. Stil pretty new with Vue.js